# Is this way reliable to checkl if current date is in between a range PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Please tell me if the below method is reliable to check if the current date in between a range

```
function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date)
 {
          // Convert to timestamp
          $start_ts = strtotime($start_date);
          $end_ts = strtotime($end_date)+86400;
          //added 86400 to check for that particular date too

          $timeNow = strtotime("now");

          // Check that user date is between start & end
          return (($timeNow >= $start_ts) && ($timeNow <= $end_ts));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the date time object like so:

```
function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date)
    {
        $startDate = new \DateTime($start_date);

        $endDate = new \DateTime($end_date);
        $endDate->add(new \DateInterval('PT86400'));

        return ((time() >= $startDate->getTimeStamp()) && (time() <= $endDate->getTimestamp()));
    }
```